# How do I download a specific service's source code off of AppEngine?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I have some php source code working in an app engine production environment that won't work anywhere else.  Old versions of that code don't seem to work at all either so I need to get that source and see what the heck it is doing differently.

This discussion outlines the challenges I'm having:
http://google-app-engine.75637.x6.nabble.com/Download-specific-Module-code-td699.html

I was told to try using appcfg.py download_app:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <APP_NAME> -V <Version> <DIR>
```

The problem is that this command does not allow me to specify module / service so I can't target my source code.  Also I'm not the App owner so I can't download everything but from what I understand that still wouldn't work because appcfg only seems to target the default service.

The article I linked ends with a suggestion to use gcloud to download the app but I haven't been able to find how to do that.  Does anyone here know how to resolve this?  The service is running in a Flexible instance - not sure if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `appcfg.py download_app --help`:

> Usage: appcfg.py [options] download_app -A app_id [ -V version ]
>
> ...
>
> -M MODULE, --module=MODULE
>                           Set the module, overriding the module value from
>                           app.yaml. ...

This invocation allowed me to download the code for the non-default  python module of :

```
appcfg.py --module=<my_module> download_app -A <my_app> .
```

Of course, you need to meet authentication and ownership requirements, etc.
And your app shouldn't have been configured for prevention of source code downloads (ireversible config)

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough to do:

1. Switch to the directory where App Engine is installed on your computer. It is usually under the following path:

   `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine`
2. Run the below command

   `appcfg.py download_app –A MyAppName -V 1 c:\AppEngine\SourceCode`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] --module=[YOUR_PROJECT_MODULE] download_app [SAVE_FOLDER]
```

**Example:**

```
appcfg.py -A foo-project --module=01-01.foo-project.appspot.com download_app foo-project-v0101
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this since none of the listed methods on the web didn't take me to the code (by June 2021)

You could try accessing your source code through;

> Google Cloud Platform > Debugger > choosing the version of the
> Application from combo at top.

This will list the files of that version on the left pane. There is no way to download it automatically but you can copy-paste the code.

Hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: appcfg.py is deprecated by google https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code