# How to list existing indexes of Google cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have a Java application running on Google App engine. We are using cloud datastore also and we created around 150 indexes in datastore.

I can see what are the indexes from GCP UI console.

I just want to see the list of indexes in local using Gcloud / appcfg tool , How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [gcloud 211.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_datastore) you can list your composite indexes with gcloud beta datastore indexes list .

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the tools has such capability, at least not presently.

AFAIK your only alternative would be to obtain the index configurations using the approach I described in the answer to your related question [How generate datastore-indexes.xml in Google App engine application (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673471/how-generate-datastore-indexes-xml-in-google-app-engine-application-java)

Comment: As I mentioned gcloud now supports listing indexes (yaml formatted).