# How to get Nodejs Source code from Google cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am a newbie to google cloud, I want to get the source code of node application that is deployed on google cloud.

I want to get that source code which is already deployed on google cloud. how can I get it?

Comment: You mean application source code

Comment: Can you expand on your question?    I understand that you want Node.js JavaScript source code.  You say that it is deployed on Google Cloud ... where?  In a Compute Engine, in a Kubernetes Cluster, in a Cloud Function?   Who deployed it?  How was it deployed?

Comment: saketh Yes.  
@Kolban I want it on my local machine. Its was deploy by some other person, however that person is not working with us now, I don't know how it was deploy.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817096/how-do-i-retrieve-my-app-engine-apps-source-code-from-the-gcloud-tool

Comment: Standard or flexible environment?

Comment: Standard environment

Comment: Try the solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499884/4495081

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have deployed an App Engine Standard Node.JS run-time application and you want to find the source code from the Google Cloud Console.

**You will have to follow the steps below:**

1. Go to Google Cloud Console App Engine page
2. Go to Services
3. Chooce the service’s source code you want to see and at the end there is a drop down menu “Tools”
4. Select from that menu “Source”
5. On the left side you will have the files with the source code.